# Get All Enum Values To A List

Tags: java, enums, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying, and failing, to retrieve all Enum values and place them in a list using Java 8 and streams. So far I've tried the two approaches below, but neither one returns the value.

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> fruits1 = Stream.of(FruitsEnum.values())
                                 .map(FruitsEnum::name)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<String> fruits2 = Stream.of(FruitsEnum.values().toString())
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // attempt 1
    System.out.println(fruits1);
    // attempt 2
    System.out.println(fruits2);
}

enum FruitsEnum {
    APPLE("APPL"),
    BANANA("BNN");

    private String fruit;

    FruitsEnum(String fruit) {this.fruit = fruit;}

    String getValue() { return fruit; }

   }
}
```

Output:

```
[APPLE, BANANA]
[[LMain$FruitsEnum;@41629346]
```

Desired:

```
["AAPL", "BNN"]
```

Comment: @Aomine, this is not a duplicate because the marked solution in that question does not work here. In fact, I had incorporated it in my snippet (`fruits1`).

Comment: I will consider reopening if you can be more specific and show the result you're currently getting and what you expect instead.

Comment: @Aomine, the result is in the output section.

Comment: what do you expect instead?

Comment: What do you expect `FruitsEnum.values().toString()` to do? Actually it'll convert the array of values to a string not to array of strings as you may expect.

Comment: I added the desired output; yes @ETO good point.

Comment: use Stream.of(FruitsEnum.values()).map(FruitsEnum::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: Why can't you simply write the enum like this, `public enum FruitsEnum {
 APPLE, BANANA;
}`

Comment: @Amit wins. He answered the correct answer while I was trying out the same thing.


`public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> fruits1 = Stream.of(FruitsEnum.values()).map(FruitsEnum::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(fruits1);
  }
`

Comment: @RavindraRanwala see [this](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA161&lpg=PA161&dq=Use+EnumMap+instead+of+ordinal+indexing&source=bl&ots=yYIfLfr5P-&sig=uDv2JHThXFPNI7LdoYZED3O39JE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0cEUUcmiNom-0QWRvYDAAw#v=onepage&q=Use%20EnumMap%20instead%20of%20ordinal%20indexing&f=false)

Comment: @HadiJ You are referring to 2nd edition. How about the same in 3rd edition? However this page is not readable for me.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala how about [this](http://thefinestartist.com/effective-java/31) ?

Comment: @HadiJ We are NOT using ordinals here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to `map` with `getValue`

```
List<String> fruits = Stream.of(FruitsEnum.values())
                            .map(FruitsEnum::getValue) // map using 'getValue'
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(fruits);
```

this will give you the output

```
[APPL, BNN]
```

Answer (score 6):

This should do the trick:

```
Arrays.stream(FruitsEnum.values())
      .map(FruitsEnum::getValue)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

Using of `EnumSet` is other way:

```
 List<String> fruits = EnumSet.allOf(FruitsEnum.class)
     .stream()
     .map(FruitsEnum::getValue)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```